How to use firebase_auth_mocks with firebase_ui_auth to mock the sign in to a flutter app during integration testing
I am trying to use the firebase_auth_mocks package along with firebase_ui_auth, Riverpod, and patrol_finders to perform integration testing.  To learn how to do this, I have created a minimal app with two screens, a Signin screen and a Profile screen. The functionality is simple: enter a (registered) user's email and password, click the signin button, and the app should take you to the Profile page.
I can run the app in a simulator, register a new user, perform the signin, and get to the Profile screen when connected to Firebase authentication.
I cannot replicate this behavior when I try to implement an integration test in which I use the firebase_auth_mocks page in place of normal Firebase authentication.
Here is the integration test:
void main() {
  String testEmail = 'bob@example.com';
  String testPassword = 'foobarbaz';
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  group('Sample Integration Test', () {
    patrolWidgetTest('Access Profile Screen', (PatrolTester $) async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setFirebaseUiIsTestMode(true);
      // 1. Set up Mock authentication.
      final user = MockUser(isAnonymous: false, email: testEmail);
      FirebaseAuth mockFirebaseAuth = MockFirebaseAuth(mockUser: user);
      AuthRepository mockAuthRepository = AuthRepository(mockFirebaseAuth);
      // 2. Start up the app, overriding providers to use mock authentication.
      await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(ProviderScope(
        overrides: [
          firebaseAuthProvider.overrideWithValue(mockFirebaseAuth),
          authRepositoryProvider.overrideWithValue(mockAuthRepository)
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ));
      // 3. Verify that the app displays the signin screen.
      expect($(#signInScreen).exists, true, reason: 'Not at SignIn screen.');
      // 4. Verify that no user is signed in.
      User? loggedInUser = mockFirebaseAuth.currentUser;
      expect(loggedInUser, null, reason: 'A user is already signed in');
      // 5. Fill out the email and password fields and submit.
      await $(EmailInput).$(TextFormField).enterText(testEmail);
      await $(PasswordInput).$(TextFormField).enterText(testPassword);
      await $(EmailForm).$(OutlinedButton).tap();
      // 6. After successful signin, should go to Profile screen.
      // However, this fails because no password is defined for this user. 
      expect($(#profileScreen).exists, true, reason: 'Not at Profile screen');
    });
  });
}

This test runs fine until the last line, where it fails because the mock authentication service does not know a password for the test user and so the SignIn screen is still displayed with an error message. I have struggled for several days to resolve this problem without success.
For example, if I try using mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), I get a Null check error where the stack trace indicates that code from the ProfileScreen is being executed even though the simulator is displaying the SignIn screen.
A repository containing this code which you can fork and run to replicate this problem is at:
https://github.com/philipmjohnson/flutter_mock_firebase_auth
Thank you for any insights or suggestions.
